# Print table header in CSS only on second page when table is too big

Tags: html, css, printing

My html page contains several tables. I implemented a print.css file in order to print correctly the page.
One on my table is cut off at the end of the 1st page (because the content is too big for being displayed on this pas). Thus the first page contains only the header of the table at the bottom and the 2nd page contains all the table. Thus the table header is repeated twice.

I would like that the table appears only on the 1st page if one part of the body can be displayed (if the body cannot be partially displayed on the first page, the table with the header should go on the next page).

I tried several css rules but it's not working for my needs:

```
table { page-break-inside:auto !important; }
tr    { page-break-inside:avoid !important; page-break-after:auto !important; }
thead { display:table-header-group !important; }
tfoot { display:table-footer-group !important; }
```

I tried also this codde but it's not working in EDGE:

```
table {
    overflow: hidden !important; 
    height: auto !important; 
    page-break-after: avoid !important; 
    page-break-before: avoid !important; 
    page-break-inside: avoid !important;
}       
table:last-child {
    page-break-after: auto !important; 
}
```

Could you please help me in order to avoid the repetition of the header (and table) when the table cannot be printed on the page?

Thanks in advance for your help